# Header on specific screen

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm working on an application with React-Native.
I'm using React-Navigation and In my login and register screens I don't want header to be shown.
this is what I wrote and it is working:

```
const Stylelist = StackNavigator({
  Login: { screen: HomeScreen}, // when finish working on homescreen, change back to LoginScreen
  Register: { screen: RegisterScreen},
  Home: { screen: HomeScreen},
},{headerMode: "none"});
```

Now I'm working on my Homescreen and I want the home screen to have an header.
How can I enable the header only on the home screen?
I tried changing "headerMode: 'none'" position but it didn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
const Stylelist = StackNavigator({
  Login: { 
    screen: HomeScreen,
    navigationOptions: ({navigation}) => ({
      header: null,
    }),  
  }
  Register: { screen: RegisterScreen },
  Home: { screen: HomeScreen },
});
```

I have never used React Navigation but I took a look at the documentation and specifically `StackNavigator` which you can see [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigators/stack#StackNavigatorConfig).

It states within the [Stack Navigator Options](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigators/stack#Screen-Navigation-Options) section that you can pass a [`header`](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigators/stack#header) which is a

> React Element or a function that given HeaderProps returns a React
>   Element, to display as a header. Setting to null hides header.

Comment: Thanks, I tried, but because of "headerMode: 'none'" it still won't display

Comment: Working great now! Thanks!